# Dúvida na implementação de ActionListener

Tags: java, swing

Tenho um projeto de faculdade para fazer um sistema de qualquer categoria que, no caso, eu escolhi um sistema médico e teve algo que eu não entendi muito bem sobre como seria a implementação:

Eu tenho um `JInternalFrame` chamado *CadastroMedico* com vários campos de texto para as informações e botões como *Salvar Cadastro, Excluir Cadastro* etc...

Foi pedido para que fosse criada uma classe chamada `MedicoListener` onde seria implementado todas as ações da classe `CadastroMedicos` em um único `ActionListener`, onde ele veria qual botão foi pressionado e realizasse tal ação,e foi ai que eu não peguei o fio da meada (Tenho uma classe Medico com getters & setters).

Como seria a implementação correta disto?

Segue a classe MedicoListener:

```
public class MedicoListener implements ActionListener {

Medico med = new Medico();
private CadastroMedico frame;

public MedicoListener(CadastroMedico frame){
    this.frame = frame;

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    //SALVAR


    //EXCLUIR

}
```

Comment: O que você não entendeu? Como funciona à orientação a eventos, como separar as operações no mesmo actionPerformed, a lógica de um algoritmo de salvamento e deleção de registros, ou todas as anteriores?

Comment: Como está sua classe CadastroMédico?

Comment: @Giuliana Eu não entendi como separar as ações no actionPerformed dentro da classe que eu citei

Comment: @diegofm A classe CadastroMedico contém o JFrame para o usuário preencher

Comment: Então, tem como adicionar como ela está? Ou o trecho com nome das variáveis dos botoes que você precisa filtrar.

Comment: @diegofm Então, nessa tela eu tenho o JButtonNovo, JButtonSalvar e JButtonExcluir, para facilitar a exemplificação vamos supor que eu tenha somente os campos código e nome para o cadastro...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode definir "*Actions commands*" para os botões e depois filtrar dentro do *Listener* através de um *switch*:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   String ActCmd = e.getActionCommand();

   switch(actCmd){

  case "SALVAR":
     //aqui você faz a lógica do salvar
     break;
  case "EXCLUIR":
     //logica do excluir

   }

}
```

E nos botoes, você precisa fazer uma pequena alteração, adicionando actions command de forma semelhante abaixo:

```
JButtonSalvar.setActionCommand("SALVAR");
JButtonExcluir.setActionCommand("EXCLUIR");
```

A alteração acima precisa ser feita na classe de construção da tela, caso esteja usando o GUI-builder do netbeans, basta adicionar após o método `initComponents()` no construtor da classe.

Como sugestão, crie métodos separados para fazer tais açoes(método separado para salvar e excluir), caso sejam complexas, e apenas chame o método específico dentro do switch...case pra que o código fique mais organizado.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Funfou certinho!

Comment: Sim! Eu precisava de uma ideia inicial, mas agora entendi perfeitamente... Já marquei hehe

Answer (score 0):

Para você saber qual botão disparou o evento, é possível utilizar o `getSource` do `ActionEvent`:

```
String comando = ((JButton) e.getSource()).getText();
if (isComandoSalvar())
   //Chamar comando salvar
else
   //Chamar comando remover
```

Dessa forma, com base no rótulo do botão que disparou o evento será possível identificar qual a operação a ser chamada, se será salvamento ou deleção do registro. Você poderia recuperar essa informação de outro atributo do `JButton`, o importante aqui é entender que a informação do componente que dispara o evento fica encapsulada no `ActionEvent` e é acessível pelo método `getSource`.

Comment: Deu certo também, obrigado Giuliana!